# Inserts and Updates getting blocked on a table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

We have lately been encountering a situation where DMLs(we only use inserts and updates) on one specific table in Postgres get blocked from time to time. Queries on all other table run just fine, albeit with some added latency because of added load.

We have noticed that autovacuum was active during some of those periods on the toasts table related to the table in question.

During one of those times, we tried to see all the queries which were stuck and we could see all updates and inserts on that particular table to be waiting for each other:

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid         AS blocked_pid, 
       blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
       blocking_locks.pid        AS blocking_pid, 
       blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
       blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement, 
       blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks blocked_locks
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks blocking_locks            ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype 
     AND blocking_locks.DATABASE      IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
     AND blocking_locks.relation      IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
     AND blocking_locks.page          IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page 
     AND blocking_locks.tuple         IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple 
     AND blocking_locks.virtualxid    IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid 
     AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid 
     AND blocking_locks.classid       IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid 
     AND blocking_locks.objid         IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid 
     AND blocking_locks.objsubid      IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
     AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid 
WHERE NOT blocked_locks.GRANTED;
```

Result:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blocked_pid                           | 28526
blocked_user                          | user
blocking_pid                          | 29151
blocking_user                         | user
blocked_statement                     | UPDATE "table_in_question" SET "response" = $1, "status_id" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "table_in_question"."id" = $4 current_statement_in_blocking_process | INSERT INTO "table_in_question" ("params_json", "test_email", "callback_url", "mail_templates_version_id", "template_name", "queue_time", "send_time", "email_ids", "status_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "uuid") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blocked_pid                           | 28526
blocked_user                          | user
blocking_pid                          | 31778
blocking_user                         | user
blocked_statement                     | UPDATE "table_in_question" SET "response" = $1, "status_id" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "table_in_question"."id" = $4 current_statement_in_blocking_process | UPDATE "table_in_question" SET "params_json" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "table_in_question"."id" = $3
```

Queries seemed to be getting blocked by each other rather than autovacuum. Although, I didn't see anything cyclic in nature here.

The table in question is one of the larger tables on the database. Although this isn't too large considering today's standards.

```
SELECT relname as "Table", 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size" 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

Result:

```
Table              |  Size   | External Size 
---------------------------------+---------+---------------
table_in_question  | 37 GB   | 10 GB
```

Postgres version:

```
select version();
     version                                                  
------------------------
PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16), 64-bit
```

Comment: You should make your query readable.. It's hard to read your query..

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @dwir182 i have made the changes